# How to inspect the HTML Select dropdown in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to inspect the items of dropdown and see styling in the inspect

I have seen many solutions but none of them worked let me give all tried solution

- Emulate a focused page
- Debugger by keyboard
- `setTimeout(() => {debugger }, 3000)`
- recursively expand and many more didn't work any

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: What does "inspect" mean? You want to inspect the element with the developer's tools?

Comment: Methinks you think the `<options>` list on-screen exists as HTML or Shadow DOM elements? It isn't. It's rendered as a native window, and not via HTML or the Shadow DOM. This is why `<select>` is notoriously un-stylable.

Comment: I see this in Chrome, styled from "user agent stylesheet: `option {
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    min-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 0px 2px 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}`